# Fix Up Regex To Not Re-Grab Old URLs From Text (JS)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

Currently I am writing my own BBCode parser. More specifically I am working on the links.

You can click on the link button, and it will insert a link (HTML `<a>`) around your text. Then that text will of course be clickable.

If you just normally write a link in the textarea, it will also make that a link automatically. Let me give you some example of what I mean so far:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com 
 Changes Automatically To
 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>

 If the user clicks the link button, and inserts it around text:
 [link=http://stackoverflow.com]Directs to SO[/link]
 It will then change that to
 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Directs to SO</a>
```

Ok now hopefully you still understand what is going on (I know I am confusing).
Here in-lies the problem, the regex that changes the BBCODE > HTML is doing it twice.

Before I continue on this let me show you my regexs:

```
.replace(/(\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\])|\[(link=)((http|https):\/\/[\S]{0,2000}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(\/[^\[\]\<\>]*)?)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/link\]/gi, function (m, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6) { return g1 ? g1 : '<a href="' + g3 + '">' + g6 + '</a>'; }) 
.replace(/(\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\])|((http|https):\/\/[\S]{0,2000}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(\/[^\[\]\<\>]*)?)/gi, function (m, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5) { return g1 ? g1 : '<a href="' + g2 + '">' + g2 + '</a>'; })
```

So basically as you can see, that converts URLS to clickable links. The `[link=___]` is not working though because the second regex is trying to rewrite the first regex again. Let me show you what I mean:

```
[link=http://stackoverflow.com]Directs to SO[/link]
First Regex Makes It This:
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Directs to SO</a>
Second Regex Then Makes It This:
<a href="<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Directs to SO</a>
```

So as you can see it is trying to convert the URLs twice.

**How could I make the SECOND regex not change URLS in the `[link]` tag a second time?**

Comment: The JavaScript RegExp engine doesn't have lookbehinds, but there are some workarounds (like using lookaheads, etc.). However, I think an important question is "Why are you trying to use regex to make a parser for a non-regular language?"

Comment: I do not think it requires lookbehinds. Any other ideas? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you're making is that you're trying to use just regular expressions. Javascript has other tools in its box.

Instead of running over the text twice, pass once with a single regex. Once you have your match, differentiate between the two cases and act appropriately. I have provided a working example based on the two regexps that you provided.

Note: **I don't actually recommend using this long, ugly regex as it is**

```
/* This long regex is just the two regexps you provided, stuck together with an OR in the middle */
var longUglyRegex = /(?:(\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\])|\[(link=)((http|https):\/\/[\S]{0,2000}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(\/[^\[\]\<\>]*)?)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/link\])|(?:(\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\])|((http|https):\/\/[\S]{0,2000}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(\/[^\[\]\<\>]*)?))/gi;
str.replace(longUglyRegex, function (m, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8) {
    if (g1) {
        return g1;
    }
    var linkText,
    linkLocation;
    if (g6) {
        // BBCode
        linkText = g6;
        linkLocation = g3;
    } else {
        // Plain URL
        linkText = linkLocation = g8;
    }
    return '<a href="' + linkLocation + '">' + linkText + '</a>';
});
```

In reality, you should write a more streamlined regex that looks roughly like this:

```
/([BBCODE])?(URL)([/link])?/
```

Note: This comes with the standard caveats that regex is not really appropriate for this task. But in your case, it may be good enough.